# How to declare variable within a SELECT?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, left-join, lateral-join

I have a long query that calculates a report refresh time and if the report didn't refresh on the "scheduled" time, then it would display late, per the cases below:

```
SELECT
RefreshStartStatus      =   CASE 
                                WHEN CS.StartTime > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP THEN 'STARTING LATER'
                                WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CS.StartTime, SA.TodayFirstRunTime) < 30 THEN 'Less than half hour late!' -- less than 30 mins late
                                WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CS.StartTime, SA.TodayFirstRunTime) >= 30 THEN 'More than half hour Late!' -- 30 mins late
                                ELSE '???'
                                END
FROM #CSTempTable CS

LEFT OUTER JOIN #SubscriptionAggTempTable SA
    ON SA.SubscriptionID = CS.SubscriptionID
```

I'd like to enhance this further and display by actually how late it was.

Since I've worked with scripts (e.g. PowerShell), it would be something as easy as

```
WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CS.StartTime, SA.TodayFirstRunTime) < 30 THEN "$(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CS.StartTime, SA.TodayFirstRunTime)) late!"
```

but of course thats not the case here with a SQL query so how would I output the actual value of how late it was? I've thought of declaring and setting a scalar variable like this:

```
DECLARE @timing int;
SET @timing = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CS.StartTime, SA.TodayFirstRunTime);

WHEN @timing < 30 THEN @timing + ' mins late!'
```

But I don't know how I can do that WITHIN the SELECT statement because the value is generated inside it due to the joins required to perform the diff...

so that it ends up like this:

```
SELECT

DECLARE @timing int;
SET @timing = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CS.StartTime, SA.TodayFirstRunTime);

RefreshStartStatus      =   CASE 
                                WHEN CS.StartTime > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP THEN 'STARTING LATER'
                                WHEN timing < 30 THEN @timing + ' mins late! a little late' -- less than 30 mins late
                                WHEN timing >= 30 THEN timing + ' mins Late! VERY LATE!' -- 30+ mins late
                                ELSE '???'
                                END
FROM #CSTempTable CS

LEFT OUTER JOIN #SubscriptionAggTempTable SA
    ON SA.SubscriptionID = CS.SubscriptionID
```

Comment: You can start a statement inside a statement no. If you need to create variables, you need to `DECLARE` them *outside* of the `SELECT`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I follow you correctly, you can use `VALUES()` and a lateral join to do the computation only once:

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN CS.StartTime > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP THEN 'STARTING LATER'
        WHEN x.timing <  30 THEN 'Less than half hour late!' 
        WHEN x.timing >= 30 THEN 'More than half hour Late!'
        ELSE '???'
    END as RefreshStartStatus,
    CASE WHEN CS.StartTime <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP THEN CONCAT(x.timing ' mins late') END as info
FROM #CSTempTable CS
LEFT OUTER JOIN #SubscriptionAggTempTable SA ON SA.SubscriptionID = CS.SubscriptionID
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CS.StartTime, SA.TodayFirstRunTime))) as x(timing)
```

Comment: This is perfect!! you also gave me a good idea to probably separate them into columns, i think tht ould make filtering better (e.g. if they wanna filter on Little late or VERY Late), and this way they can see by how late it was in the separate info column. Love this answer!!

Comment: Looks like a comma is missing here `(x.timing ' mins late')`. also when it hits the `'???'` status it outputs "mins late" in the info, which is expected, but how can i have a NULL or "Unknown Status" displayed instead if the expression gets evaluated as ???

Comment: Instead of CROSS APPLY (VALUES, could also do something like: 
CROSS APPLY (SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CS.StartTime, SA.TodayFirstRunTime) as timing) x